# ROS Answers SE migration: custom rqt gui

Tags: ros, rqt-gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like this question I cannot answer by myself:

http://answers.ros.org/question/200876/rqt-custom-imageview-showing-images-from-different-cameras/

I thought about that serveral times but I am going to ask a bit more general:

We all know as a user you can configure the appearance of rqt_gui, (which plugin widgets, positions, some state variables of the widgets etc.) yourself.

Now I as a developer your like to have a custom gui for my user, i. e. I do not want that my user has to configure the appearance initially but I as developer want to provide the initial arrangement of the rqt plugins, maybe along with some custom plugin widgets. Is this kind of predefining the arrangement of the rqt gui possible by providing an XML, python, whatever script? Ideally I would also be able to set some state variables, e. g. topic names as asked in the linked question? Could I launch this predefined arrangement using an executable (script) in my  own package (rather than rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201064/custom-rqt-gui/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

+1 to @gvdhoorn's answer; I just totally forgot what I answered years ago. That solution is not entirely systematic, but fairly nice and easy approach if that fits in whatever need.

I just [dropped a time-taking but more robust solution](http://answers.ros.org/question/200876/rqt-custom-imageview-showing-images-from-different-cameras/?answer=201074#post-id-201074) to the thread you referred to. By creating a relatively simple rqt plugin on your own, you can now have a full control in detail.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a complete answer, but `rqt_gui` does support the concept of *perspectives*, see [Set rqt_gui Perspectives from Command Line](http://answers.ros.org/question/53721/set-rqt_gui-perspectives-from-command-line/) for instance.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3